# Получение данных с веб страницы в формате JSON

Tags: python, json, http

API сайта позволяет получать данные в формате json:

```
{
 "query": {
  "count": 2
},
" results": {
  "EUR_RUB": {
    "id": "EUR_RUB",
    "val": 75.489179,
    "to": "RUB",
    "fr": "EUR"
},
  "USD_RUB": {
    "id": "USD_RUB",
    "val": 66.343801,
    "to": "RUB",
    "fr": "USD"
   }
  }
}
```

Пытаюсь получить из него данные:

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen('https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=EUR_RUB,USD_RUB') as response:
    source = response.read()

data = json.loads(source)

for item in data["results"]:
    print(item)
```

Но, после отработки скрипта, получаю только:

```
 EUR_RUB
 USD_RUB
```

Подскажите, как корректно написать запрос.

Comment: print(data["results"][item])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for item in data["results"]:
>           print(item)

При таком цикле перебираются только *ключи* словаря. Если хотите перебрать все пары **ключ:значение**, используйте:

```
for key, value in data["results"].items():
    print(key, value)
```

Если только значения:

```
for value in data["results"].values():
    print(value)
```

Answer (score 4):

Пример с использованием модуля [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```
In [86]: import requests

In [87]: url = 'https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=EUR_RUB,USD_RUB'

In [88]: r = requests.get(url)

In [89]: data = r.json()
```

Результат:

```
In [90]: data
Out[90]:
{'query': {'count': 2},
 'results': {'EUR_RUB': {'id': 'EUR_RUB',
   'val': 75.436655,
   'to': 'RUB',
   'fr': 'EUR'},
  'USD_RUB': {'id': 'USD_RUB', 'val': 66.270102, 'to': 'RUB', 'fr': 'USD'}}}

In [91]: data['results']
Out[91]:
{'EUR_RUB': {'id': 'EUR_RUB', 'val': 75.436655, 'to': 'RUB', 'fr': 'EUR'},
 'USD_RUB': {'id': 'USD_RUB', 'val': 66.270102, 'to': 'RUB', 'fr': 'USD'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys; print 'Python %s' % (sys.version)
#Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

import urllib
import ssl
import urllib2
import json

x = ssl.create_default_context()
x.check_hostname = False
x.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}

params = urllib.urlencode({})
# params = urllib.urlencode({'q': 'EUR_RUB,USD_RUB'})

s = urllib2.Request('https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=EUR_RUB,USD_RUB', params, headers)
# s = urllib2.Request('https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert', params, headers)
s_responce = urllib2.urlopen(s, context=x)
data = s_responce.read()
my_json = json.loads(data[1])
```